# Targeted horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to target html elements that I don't want to affect the width of the page?
In other words, those elements wouldn't trigger the horizontal scrollbar, if they were to leave the browser box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking other sites structures, the solution seems to be pretty simple:

Wrapping everything in a relative positioned container(with overflow:hidden) lets the container grow with the contents of the page, while not letting the elements show out of it's borders.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/LnNQJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS `overflow: hidden` to keep them from affecting your layout.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is one of the 1st things to check when evaluating layout issues.

Comment: I do not know who downvoted your comment. It is one of the first things i look for when analyzing layout issues as well.

Comment: But doesn't overflow:hidden rule apply to the visibility of the children of the affected element? In my case, the parent is the browser view box, the <body>. If I set its overflow to hidden, you know what happens, everything gets cut out.

Comment: It would, yes. Given the question above, that is how I understood it. If you like, give us a sample of what you have in mind (paste code in your question or use jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow:hidden` on the elements you don't want the scrollbar on.

You can also use `overflow-x:hidden` or `overflow-y:hidden` [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)